# Formula that gives workdays given starting day of the week as number and number of days?

Tags: python, math, formula

I'm trying to come up with a formula (No ifs/else, only sum, subtraction, division, multiplication and mod) to com up with working days.

Workdays are days of the week 1-5

Given :

Day of the week as an integer between 1-7 (you can use 0-6 in your answer)

Number of days from day of the week between 1-n

Example input :

```
week_day = 1 //monday
days = 10
```

Should output :

```
workdays = 8
```

I believe the formula should be something around the mod operator, but not even sure where to start.

What I have so far only works if week_day < 5 :

```
week_day = 1
days = 16

saturday_day = 6
sunday_day = 7

saturdays = days/saturday_day
sundays = days/sunday_day

weekends = saturdays+sundays

workdays = days - weekends
```

I believe to make it work, `saturday_day` and `sunday_day` need to shift forward(or backward?) based on the `week_day`, but they both have to be between 1-7, that's where mod would come in I guess.

Comment: `0-6` plays nicer with modular arithmetic than 1-7. I would work out a formula assuming 0-based arithmetic then shift the formula to 1-based when you are done.

Comment: Just minus, sum, division, multiplication and mod

Comment: @JohnColeman and yes using 0 based is fine

Comment: These arbitrary restrictions on what you can use makes it seem like homework rather than a practical programming question. As homework, we wouldn't want to ruin the learning experience and do it for you. So, what have you tried and where are you stuck? As a hint, the division algorithm with divisor 7( expressing a number as a quotient and remainder when dividing by 7) is a good place to start.

Comment: It has no practical use, its more for research, I will post what I have

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the underlying problem is related to math and not programming.

Comment: @Georgy I don't really see that. The question is how to *compute* something using a computer programming language. Almost by definition, anything on the `math` tag involves issues outside of just programming, but that doesn't make them all off-topic. There is enough code here to make it on-topic (at least in my opinion).

Comment: @JohnColeman I wasn't convinced so I did some reading on meta and it looks like you are right: [Isn't this a math question that should be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335730), [Are questions asking for a mathematical formula on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300689). I retracted my flag now. Though, if it would be me asking this question, I would go to math.SE first to learn about math behind, and only after that asked a question here about implementation

Comment: @Georgy The borderline between math and CS is fuzzy, and this fuzziness really shows up on the math tag. I've voted to close a number of questions on the tag because they really were straight math questions. But, if something shows code and asks for help in making the code work, I tend to give it the benefit of the doubt, even if the main obstruction to fixing the code is mathematical in nature. For this reason I will vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my somewhat straightforward and rigorous solution.  There could very well be an optimized way to do this:

```
# Determine the minimum of two integers without any branching (no `if`)
def min(x, y):
    return y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y))

# assuming that start is 1-7 with 1 being Monday
def compute_work_days(start, days):
    # work in a 0-based scale (0 == Monday)
    start -= 1

    # remember our original start
    orig_start = start

    # adjust count so that we assume we start on the earlier Monday and 
    # end on the same day
    days += start

    # pull out full weeks, which provide 5 work days and otherwise leave the same problem
    full_weeks = days // 7      # compute number of full weeks
    days = days % 7             # take these even weeks out of the count
    work_days = full_weeks * 5  # we get 5 work days for each full week

    # what we have left is a value between 0 and 6, where the first 5 days
    # are work days, so add at most 5 days
    work_days += min(days, 5)

    # now take off the extra days we added to the count at the beginning, the
    # first 5 of which will be work days
    work_days -= min(orig_start, 5)

    return work_days
```

Comment: Nice start (+1) but the problem is the min operator. It is an `if` in disguise (it is basically `def min(x,y): return x if x < y else y`). You need a trick to get rid of `min`. I don't think that `min` in all its glory is needed. It is only for a strictly finite list of inputs, which by polynomial interpolation can be done with just multiplication, addition, and subtraction.

Comment: Ah.  Great point.  It isn't clear to me quite yet how best to get rid of 'min' but I'll come up with a way.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if `xor` is off the table...don't know why it would be, as it's the most fundamental of CPU operations.  I've updated my answer to use `xor` and provide a version of the `min` function that does no branching.

Answer (score 1):

Let n denote the number of worked days and d a weekday in {1, 2, ..., 7}, then the number of workdays w maybe computed as following:

[image]

Hint: floor(x/d) is the number of multiples of d that are less than or equals to x.